# Chrome 52 Object.keys bug inside object js proxy?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Starting from Chrome 52 Object.keys show also non enumerable fields if called inside a proxy. Chrome 51 was ok. Also Edge and Firefox is ok.

This is a stupid test to show it. Just run it on Chrome 52 to show wrong behavior:

```js
var target={};
Object.defineProperty(target,"__observerCallbacks__",{enumerable:false,configurable:true,writable:false,value:['aaaa']});
var ori='';
Object.keys(target).forEach(
  function(x){
     ori+=x;
  }
);
var proxy='';
var p = new Proxy(target, {get:function(target,property)
    {
        return property;
    }
});
Object.keys(p).forEach(
  function(x){
    //if (window.target.propertyIsEnumerable(x)){
        proxy+=x;
    //}
  }
);
//alert('ori '+ori+' proxy '+proxy);
console.log('ori', ori, 'proxy', proxy)
```

Does anyone ran into this issue? Any suggestions? Monkey patch?

Comment: file a bug with goggle?

Comment: Oh, wow, it _is_ a bug.

Comment: Opened bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=632287&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the bug test a little bit. I did run this on Chrome 51 then Chrome 52, and the behavior is indeed different. In Chrome 51, `tKeys` is equal to `pKeys` while `tNames` is equal to `pNames`, but in Chrome 52, `tKeys` is equal to `tNames`, which seems to be problematic.

Changing `__observerCallbacks__` to another property name does not seem to resolve the issue, so the name of the property is unrelated. I would suggest you file this bug report with Google.

On a side note, the property descriptors for some reason change the `value` from `["aaaa"]` to `"_"` when the property name is `__observerCallbacks__`. I'm not sure why it's doing that, but I don't think it's related since it's specific to that property name.

```js
var target = {};

Object.defineProperty(target, "__observerCallbacks__", {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true,
  writable: false,
  value: ['aaaa']
});

var tKeys = Object.keys(target);
var tNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target);
var tProps = tNames.map(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor.bind(target));
var tValue = target.__observerCallbacks__;

var proxy = new Proxy(target, {
  get: function(target, property) {
    return property;
  }
});

var pKeys = Object.keys(proxy);
var pNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proxy);
var pProps = pNames.map(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor.bind(proxy));
var pValue = proxy.__observerCallbacks__;

console.log('target keys:', tKeys);
console.log('target own names:', tNames);
console.log('target property descriptors:', tProps);
console.log('target value:', tValue);

console.log('proxy keys:', pKeys);
console.log('proxy own names:', pNames);
console.log('proxy property descriptors', pProps);
console.log('proxy value:', pValue);
```

Comment: opened bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=632287&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=